# Expected value of independent bias coin toss

Tags: probability

Consider a sequence of independent tosses of a biased coin at times t = 0, 1, 2, . . .. On each toss,
the probability of a ’head’ is p, and the probability of a ’tail’ is 1 − p. A reward of one unit is
given each time that a ’tail’ follows immediately after a ’head.’ Let R be the total reward paid
in times 1, 2, . . . , n. Find E[R] and var(R).

in solution paper 
$$E[I_k^2] =p(1-p)$$
$$E[I_kI_{k+1}] =0$$
$$E[I_kI_{k+l}] =p^2(1-p)^2 for \space l\ge2$$
$$E[R^2] =E[(\sum_{k=1}^n I_k)(\sum_{m=1}^n I_m)]=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{m=1}^nE[I_kI_m]\\=np(1-p)+0+(n^2-3n+2)p^2(1-p)^2$$
I couldn't understand this process above could you explain,especially$$(n^2-3n+2)$$

Comment: Use indicator variables, with one variable for each of the positions $2, \cdots, n$ in which you might get a reward.

Comment: With just two tosses the probability of a tail following ahead is $p(1-p)$.  That and the number of pairs (which might overlap) would give you the expectation quickly.  The variance is slightly more complicated since such patterns cannot overlap, and so the variance will be lower than the corresponding binomial variance.  You might find it easier to calculate $E[R^2] -(E[R])^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for $t=0,1,\dots,n$ we denote the event on heads at time $t$ by $H_t$ and the event of tails by $T_t$ then $I_k$ can be recognized as indicator function of event $H_{k-1}\cap T_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$.

On RHS of the calculation of $\mathbb ER^2$ there are $n^2$ terms in total.

$n$ of these terms (i.e. those of shape $\mathbb EI_k^2$) take value $p(p-1)$.

$2(n-1)$ of these terms (i.e. those of shape $\mathbb EI_kI_{k+1}$) take value $0$.

The remaining $n^2-n-2(n-1)=n^2-3n+2$ of them take value $p^2(1-p)^2$.

This together justifies the conclusion that:$$\mathbb ER^2=np(p-1)+(n^2-3n+2)p^2(1-p)^2$$